# PHP Header Redirect taking user to blank page

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect, header

I am attempting to redirect users across domains that I own using a PHP header redirect.

I am currently using:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$local_Dir = '../';
include $local_Dir.'resources/php/local_variables.php';

if( !headers_sent() ){
    header("Location: ".$system_domain_url."?refresh=1");
}else{
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.location.href="<?php echo $system_domain_url; ?>?refresh=1";
  </script>
  Redirecting to <a href="<?php echo $system_domain_url; ?>?refresh=1"><?php echo $system_domain_url; ?></a>
  <?php
}

ob_end_flush();
die();
```

However, for some reason, it is not redirecting completely.
To clarify, it does take the browser to the correct url, but the page is visually blank. Looking at the page source shows that all HTML has been loaded appropriately, but it is still not showing up.

The code inspector in firefox shows (not the content visible in page source) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            :root #content > #right > .dose > .dosesingle,
            :root #content > #center > .dose > .dosesingle,
            :root #header + #content > #left > #rlblock_left
            { display: none !important; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have already ensured that there is no white space in this or the other included files.
I have also used ob_start and end to ensure content is not outputted prematurely.

I am running out of ides.

I would appreciate all help!

Thank you!

Comment: well without the code for the page that isn't displaying there is not much one can do.  What happens when you go there manually.  I imagine you redirect is fine and you have an issue on the other page.

Comment: when you get to that page what happens when you do a manual refresh?

Comment: Do you use jQuery on a target page? Does resizing the target page help displaying its content (resizing the window)? I ran into a similar problem once, when the content of a page was hidden until it was resized or scrolled